# IRepositories is null in account controller with Unity DI

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, unity-container, asp.net-identity

I'm using Unity DI in my application. I have register my Repositories in `UnityConfig.cs` file.

```
 public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
 {
     // NOTE: To load from web.config uncomment the line below. Make sure to add a Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration to the using statements.
     // container.LoadConfiguration();

     container.RegisterType<DbContext, RanoChatDbContext>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
     container.RegisterType<UserManager<AppUser>>( new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
     container.RegisterType<IUserStore<AppUser>, UserStore<AppUser>>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
     container.RegisterType<AccountController>( new InjectionConstructor());
     container.RegisterType<IRepositories, Repositories>();
 }
```

and In `AccountController`

```
private ApplicationSignInManager _signInManager;
private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;
private IRepositories repos;

public AccountController()
{            
}

public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager,
                         ApplicationSignInManager signInManager,
                         IRepositories Repositories)
{
    repos = Repositories;
    UserManager = userManager;
    SignInManager = signInManager;
}
```

But repos is `null`

while the same repos was intialized correctly in my HomeController.

```
IRepositories repos;

public HomeController(IRepositories repos)
{
    this.repos = repos;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably your 3-arg constructor has other types that Unity doesn't know how to inject (ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationSignInManager) because you didn't register those types.

```
public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager,
                         ApplicationSignInManager signInManager, 
                         IRepositories Repositories)
```

Also, it may simply be calling the controller's zero-arg constructor. Tell Unity how you want it to instantiate the controller by registering it with something like:

```
container.RegisterType<AccountController>(new InjectionConstructor(typeof(Repositories)));
```

See MSDN - [Registering Injected Parameter and Property Values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Ff660882(v=PandP.20).aspx)

Comment: I created another controller with `IRepositories` .`public AccountController(IRepositories repos)
        {
            this.repos = repos;
        }` but still it is null.

Comment: Then How It will get initialize ?

Comment: I'm saying you need to confirm which constructor Unity is using to instantiate AccountController. It is probably calling the default constructor. You can configure it to do otherwise.

Comment: Thanks . your last help me to sort out my problem .
`container.RegisterType<AccountController>(new InjectionConstructor(typeof(Repositories)));`